# Angular Universal: prevent ngrx from replacing a SSR rendered value

Tags: angular, ngrx, angular-universal, flicker, hydration

I'm currently using Angular 16 with Angular Universal.

I have a REST API call that returns list of items which are stored in ngrx. These items are then selected via a ngrx selector and rendered using *ngFor.

When the page is returned, these items are present in the response and rendered correctly, but then immediatly removed (I am guessing due to angular client-side reactivity). Then, the same REST API is called by the browser, and the array is rendered again.

This causes a flicker effect, which is quite horrible. I've been reading about hydration in Angular 16, but I am unable to fix it. I've tried using provideClientHydration, but I'm sure that's not as related to my issue as I initially thought.

Comment: You need to use [`TransferState`](https://angular.io/api/core/TransferState) where you set a value during SSR, and retrieve the value when `!IsPlatformServer`

Comment: Angular 16's hydration will only allow the angular runtime to reuse the existing html elements which came in the server response, rather than clearing and recreating all elements again. Data in the model still needs to be restored through your code

Comment: I've noticed what you say about Angular 16 hydration, but I read that it should catch HttpClient get requests. However, it is not working, and my calls are being repeated client-side.

About TransferState, I'd really appreciate it if you could provide an example of setting / reading a value. I'd like to automatically populate my ngrx store, but it seems like that would be quite complex. Thank you for you time

Comment: [Click here to open an early christmas present](https://github.com/PieterjanDeClippel/TransferStateDemo/blob/master/src/app/app.component.ts#L19)

Comment: Thank you for your time again. I've been able to make HttpClient cache work by using provideClientHydration. Your response, however, is very useful for loading specific values.